# looking for an std algorithm to replace a simple for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++20, array-algorithms

Is there a standard algorithm in the library that does the job of the following for-loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main( )
{
    const char oldFillCharacter { '-' };
    std::vector<char> vec( 10, oldFillCharacter ); // construct with 10 chars
    // modify some of the elements
    vec[1] = 'e';
    vec[7] = 'x';
    vec[9] = '{';

    const char newFillCharacter { '#' };

    for ( auto& elem : vec ) // change the fill character of the container
    {
        if ( elem == oldFillCharacter )
        {
            elem = newFillCharacter;
        }
    }

    // output to stdout
    std::copy( std::begin( vec ), std::end( vec ),
               std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';
    /* prints: # e # # # # # x # { */
}
```

I want to replace the above *range-based for-loop* with a **one-liner** if possible. Is there any function that does this? I looked at [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) but I guess it's not suitable for such a scenario.

Comment: How about plain [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to do, on a high level.  In that code, there are several things going on, and what are we supposed to be pinpointing?

Comment: So to boil this down, are you simply trying to replace one value with another in a sequence of values?  If so, that's what you should state up front -- no need to show code or other things that may confuse what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. Simple as that. I just wanted a one-liner instead of a dummy loop.

Comment: Well, googling "STL algorithm to replace" would have probably gotten you to `std::replace` or `std::replace_if`.  Doing a web search for `for` loops wouldn't take you to what you are looking for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I forgot to Google search. I just kept on searching on cppreference and didn't even search for the word *replace*!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This loop will replace every occurrence of `oldFillCharacter` with `newFillCharacter`. If you don't want to do something more fancy [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) looks good:

```
std::replace(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), oldFillCharacter, newFillCharacter);
```

Or a bit simpler with [`std::ranges::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/replace):

```
std::ranges::replace(vec, oldFillCharacter, newFillCharacter);
```

Comment: I was totally unaware of this algorithm. Seems like the most suitable one. Also thanks for suggesting the `ranges` variation!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::for_each`.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](char& elem) { 
    if ( elem == oldFillCharacter ) elem = newFillCharacter;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::replace(vec.begin(), vec.end(), '_', '#');
```