# How to use C++ std::ranges to replace substring in string?

Tags: c++, string, replace, c++20, std-ranges

I know how to replace characters in vector using std::replace as in: [ranges::replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793245/looking-for-an-std-algorithm-to-replace-a-simple-for-loop)

I would lie to do something similar with substrings in a string. E.g:

```
std::string str{"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
std::ranges::replace(str, "the", "a");
```

But I get an error:

> error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__replace_fn) (std::string&, const char [4], const char [2])'

Or if I use strings

> error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__replace_fn) (std::string&, std::string&, std::string&)'

It works for *characters*, but not for substrings.

Any ideas?

I have successfully used a loop and `string.find` and `string.replace`, but would like to use ranges.

Comment: This contradicts the semantics of `std::ranges::replace`, as replace refers to *each element* in the given range. May be you want to split `str` by whitespace and then replace word by word using `std::ranges::replace`?

Comment: Why not use string_view instead?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c

Comment: @Patrick Roocks Splitting the string would work if there is a useful delimiter, such as a space. Not always the case, but a useful suggestion to keep in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::ranges::replace` replaces elements in a range, you want to replace a subrange with another subrange. As far as I know, there is currently no algorithm for it in the standard library.

## Using `std::regex`:

I would just use `std::regex`:

```cpp
std::string str{"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."};
std::cout << std::regex_replace(str,std::regex("the"), "a") << std::endl;
```

```
The quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog.
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q4c6dzzPP

## Using `std::ranges`:

If you really *really* want to use `std::ranges`, you could split your range at the given pattern, insert the replacement at the splits and then join the range.

### Using `std::ranges` in C++23:

C++23 conveniently provides a function `std::views::join_with` *(that hasn't been widely adapted yet as of the time of writing this)*:

```cpp
auto replace_view(std::string_view str, std::string_view pattern, std::string_view replacement)
{
    return str | std::views::split(pattern) | std::views::join_with(replacement);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nd8zardE5

### Using `std::ranges` in C++20:

You can get it to work in C++20 as well, you just need to put in a bit more work:

```cpp
auto replace_view(std::string_view str, std::string_view pattern, std::string_view replacement)
{
    return str 
        // split at pattern
        | std::views::split(pattern) 
        // prefix each subrange with the replacement
        | std::views::transform(
            [replacement](auto const& substr){ 
                return std::string(replacement) + std::string(substr.begin(), substr.end()); 
            }
        )
        // join the subranges to a single range
        | std::views::join
        // drop the first occurance of the replacement
        | std::views::drop(replacement.size());
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/j1WMWdW1h

Comment: Great answers. Thanks. Might just go with the regexp.